# Javascript DRY methodology for auto assigning variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I find myself repeating this, mostly out of laziness but im wondering now if there is a nice concise way to handle this or how people do this also happy to use lodash/underscore etc

```
# Client Side 

export interface User {
    name: string
    address: string 
    age: number
    city: string 
    country: string 
    friends: any[]
}

cont user: Partial<User> = {
    name: "Joey",
    city: "New York",    
}

api.registerUser(user)
```

then over on the server with expressJS i have a function like this where I have to pluck out each item from a request var called params, I know I could do something with `Object.keys` etc but maybe there is a better solution or 1 liners etc for handling this kind of scenario, basically i want to auto assign everything in params to a variable of the same name and save to the db using the same key as the variable name - what would also be great is if I could sometimes match these variables against the interface to make sure that they are all there - sometimes interface items are optional client side but server side are required for instance when creating a user the ID is optional as it only gets generated when the user is stored but for updates its required.

```
# Server side 
function registerUser(req: ServerRequest) {
    # This is not very DRY (dont repeat yourself-ish)
    cont user = req.parms
        name = user.name 
        city = user.city 
        address = user.address 
        age = user.age     
        country = user.country         
        friends = user.friends     
    
    # is there a way to iterate over an interface and output variables which are named according to their matching interface counterparts 
    # whilst also checking or being able to do a check to see what items are missing and handle it by either skipping or assigning a default value
            
}
```

Comment: While indeed verbose, and while @Ava's answer suggests a helpful alternative to address this, the original code doesn't actually violate DRY.

Comment: It does if your creating a lot of CRUD endpoints and checking for the same params all the time

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use destructuring?

```js
const { name, city, address, age, country, friends } = req.params;

// you can use default value this way. Let's say the `name` is missing.
const { name = 'Ava', city, address, age, country, friends } = req.params;
console.log(name);
// Output: Ava

// For typescript you can do
interface User {
    name: string,
    city: string,
    address: string,
    age: number,
    country: string,
    friends: string
}

// Sorry I don't know what `type` is `friends` so I assumed it `string`.
const { name = 'Ava', city, address, age, country, friends } : User = req.params;
```

You can read about destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: I should have guessed this :) and friends is an array type